# Error in read.table duplicate row.names

Tags: r

When I tried to read the following table into dataframe (data100) by:

```
data100 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
                                 verb_object SESSION_ID
1:   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT   41595370
2: BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE   41595371
3:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE   41595282
4:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE   41595282
5: 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE   41595373
6:   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT   41595368
')

I get the following error:
Error in read.table(header = TRUE, text = "\n                               verb_object SESSION_ID\n   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT   41595370\n                      BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE   41595371\n                         26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE   41595282\n                         26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE   41595282\n                     2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE   41595373\n                         6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT   41595368\n") : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

How can I read it?

After usage of

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection("       verb_object SESSION_ID



> data100<-read.table(text=gsub('(?<=\\:)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\s[0-9])', " '", lines, perl=TRUE), sep='', fill=TRUE)
```

The result is as followed:

```
> data100
           V1                               V2       V3       V4 V5                                         V6       V7
1 verb_object                       SESSION_ID                NA                                                     NA
2         1:  BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5   INSERT 41595370 2: BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE  41595371
3         3:  26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7   UPDATE 41595282 4:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE  41595282
4         5:  2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE 41595373 6:   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT  41595368
>
```

Comment: The first column have two words, which give me the error `more columns than column names`.  If you have only 6 rows, just quote the string `'BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT'` and in `read.table(header=TRUE, text="....")`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, but what to do in case I have many rows?

Comment: Posted a possible solution, which worked based on the example showed.

Comment: Based on your output, no idea how you got two lines merged into a single row.  THe code was perfectly working for me and in your output, the `header` column is automatically generated.  Did you used `header=TRUE`?

Comment: No. I just copied the commands you sent in the answer.

Comment: Did you had spaces `readLines(textConnection("       verb_object SESSION_ID` or it is just like I showed in the post `readLines(textConnection("verb_object ..."

Comment: Can you show the ouput of `lines` in the post?

Comment: Bingo! The problem was with spaces inside the matrix and in the headline. If I want to handle both cases what can I do?

Comment: I guess the spaces in your file got somehow changed while posting.  Can you upload the original file in dropbox or somewhere from which I can download?  One option if this is a `leading/lagging` space, `library(stringr); lines <- str_trim(lines)` and then use the `read.table` code.

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Can you send me an email so I'll be able to send you. I have additional matrix to load and I get: Error in read.table(text = gsub("(?<=\\:)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\s[0-9])", " '",  : 
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'text'

Comment: You can load it in dropbox and share the link.

Comment: I don't have an access to dropbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93912/discussion-between-akrun-and-avi).

Comment: Based on the new dataset, try `read.table(text=gsub("[^:]+:\\s+([^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+)\\s+(.*)$", "'\\1' \\2", lines), header=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read it with `readLines`, place the quotes using `gsub`, and read with `read.table`

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection("verb_object SESSION_ID
1:   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT   41595370
2: BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE   41595371
3:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE   41595282
4:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE   41595282
5: 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE   41595373
6:   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT   41595368"))



read.table(text=gsub('(?<=\\:)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\s[0-9])', " '", lines, perl=TRUE), sep='')
#                                  verb_object SESSION_ID
#1:   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT    41595370
#2: BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE    41595371
#3:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE    41595282
#4:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE    41595282
#5: 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE    41595373
#6:   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT    41595368
```

#### Update

The OP's new dataset can be read with `readLines` as before,

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection("items newitem
1: BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT OV1
2: BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE OV2
3: 26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE OV3
4: 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE OV4
5: 6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT OV5"))
```

We should note that the pattern we matched in the earlier dataset (`\\s+(?=\\s[0-9])`) won't work here as the first character in 'SESSIONID' is number, while in 'newitem' it is a uppercase letter.  So, we match one or more characters that are not `:` from the beginning of the string (`^[^:]+`) followed by `:`, followed by one or more space (`\\s+`), then we capture the characters as a group using parentheses `()` i.e. one or more characters that are not space followed by one or more space and characters not space (`([^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+)`, match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by one or more characters till the end of the string as another capture group (`(.*)$`).  We replace by placing quotes around the first capture group (`'\\1'`) followed by space followed by second capture group.

```
read.table(text=gsub("^[^:]+:\\s+([^ ]+\\s+[^ ]+)\\s+(.*)$",
         "'\\1' \\2", lines), header=TRUE)
#                                     items newitem
#1   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT     OV1
#2 BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE     OV2
#3   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE     OV3
#4 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE     OV4
#5   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT     OV5
```

Comment: the line command is excellent but in read,table I get the following error: > data100<-read.table(text=gsub('(?<=\\:)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\s[0-9])', " '", lines, perl=TRUE), sep='')
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 7 elements

Comment: @Avi It is because in the original dataset there might be some missing values, use `filll=TRUE` in read.table

Comment: Thanks, @akrun, Can you please tell me where to add fill=TRUE in read.table?

Comment: @Avi  Try `read.table(text=gsub('(?<=\\:)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\s[0-9])', " '", lines, perl=TRUE), sep='', fill=TRUE)`

Comment: I tried still not what I need: > data100<-read.table(text=gsub('(?<=\\:)\\s+|\\s+(?=\\s[0-9])', " '", lines, perl=TRUE), sep='', fill=TRUE)
> data100
           V1                               V2       V3       V4 V5                                         V6       V7
1 verb_object                       SESSION_ID                NA                                                     NA
2         1:  BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5   INSERT 41595370 2: BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE  41595371

Comment: @Avi Can you update your post with few lines of the original dataset.